# Move div with CSS translate on hover but cursor stay move in the previous position

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transform

Can anyone help me to create a translation transition on hover in the div when the cursor moves the previous area position of the div?

I have tried:

```css
#test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}

#test:hover {
  transform: translate(300px, 0px);
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area 
</div>
```

As you can see, the div always translates when the cursor moves in the previous position of the div. But I want the translation stopped even if the cursor moves in the previous area. Thanks

---

Illustration:

[image]

Comment: Please specify a little more of your expected output. What exactly does "I want the translation stopped even if the cursor moves in the previous area" mean?

Comment: so the div will only move on the first hover. After that I want the div to stay in the new position while the cursor is still moving in the previous position of the div area.

Comment: If I understand correctly, once the div is hovered, the animation will play and not stop until the animation is complete, regardless of user interaction? You'll need JavaScript to achieve this.

Comment: @code I just add the illustration to make this question easy to understand. But I want pure CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a wrapper, then use `:hover` on it instead (note that it is `inline-block`):

```css
#test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}

#wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
}

#wrapper:hover > #test {
  transform: translate(300px, 0px);
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="test">
    Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As your illustration shows, we can use some box that stays in the previous position. That box may be an actual element (like [the `#wrapper` in InSync's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75752643/13561410)), or a pseudo-element.

The initial problem with using a pseudo-element is: Since it is a child, it will naturally follow its translating parent.

To make it "stay in place", we need the pseudo-element to e.g. **translate into the opposite direction**:

```css
#test {position: relative} /*Non-`static` position required for `absolute`.*/
#test::before {
  content: "";
  
  /*Make similar size to parent and place on top:*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#test:hover::before {
  /*Translate opposite on hover*/
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}

/*Your CSS:*/
#test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
#test:hover {
  transform: translate(300px, 0px);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area <button onclick="console.log('Pressed')">Press</button>
</div>
```

Notice how the pseudo-element is placed *in front of other content* because of `position: absolute`. This obstructs the actual content e.g. from receiving pointer events.

But we can **use the [`z-index` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to place it behind** other content.

By declaring `z-index: -1` on the pseudo-element, it will be placed behind. Unfortunately, it will also be placed behind *any ancestor* in the same [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

```css
#ancestor {background-color: lightpink}
#test::before {z-index: -1}

/*Previous CSS:*/
#test {position: relative}
#test::before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  opacity: .6;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#test:hover::before {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}

#test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
#test:hover {
  transform: translate(300px, 0px);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="ancestor">
  <div id="test">
    Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area <button onclick="console.log('Pressed')">Press</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

The [CSS Transforms Module Level 1 specification](https://w3c.github.io/csswg-drafts/css-transforms/#transform-rendering) reads:

> For elements whose layout is governed by the CSS box model,
> any value other than `none` for the `transform` property results in
> the creation of a stacking context.

Simply put: Luckily the pseudo-element is where it is supposed to be when needed; when `#test` is translating.

Alternatively, we could establish a new stacking context to always exist by declaring `z-index: 0` on `#test`.

```css
#test {z-index: 0}

/*Previous CSS:*/
#ancestor {background-color: lightpink}
#test::before {z-index: -1}

#test {position: relative}
#test::before {
  content: "";
  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#test:hover::before {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}

#test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
#test:hover {
  transform: translate(300px, 0px);
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id="ancestor">
  <div id="test">
    Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area <button onclick="console.log('Pressed')">Press</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: The pseudo-element is still placed in front of `#test`'s box, so it will still obstruct `#test`'s background. Since the pseudo-element will be transparent, this shouldn't be an issue.

---

If you want the transition to also apply when not hovering, simply declare it on `#test` (instead of on `#test:hover`):

```css
#ancestor {background-color: lightpink}

#test {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
#test:hover {
  transform: translate(300px, 0px);
}

#test::before {
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
#test:hover::before {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="ancestor">
  <div id="test">
    Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area <button onclick="console.log('Pressed')">Press</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note**: Don't forget to make the pseudo-element also transition when not hovering!

Comment: Great answer, but I want a transition when the cursor stops hovering.

Comment: @Jordy Please tell me whether my addendum helps you with that.

Answer (score -1):

Is the onMouseOver function did answer the question?
I'm sorry, but i hope it could help you in some ways.

Here how:

```js
function moveToRight(){
  let myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
  myDiv.style.transform = "translate(300px, 0px)";
  myDiv.style.transition = "all 3s ease";
}
```

```css
#test {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test" onMouseOver="moveToRight()">
  Hover me but the cursor always moves in the previous position of the div's area 
</div>
```

Comment: The div is not back to the previous position when the cursor stop hovering.